# Multiple Evaluators in CrossValidator - Spark ML

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-ml

Is it possible to have more than 1 evaluator in a `CrossValidator` to get **R2** and **RMSE** at the same time?

Instead of having two different `CrossValidator`:

```
    val lr_evaluator_rmse = new RegressionEvaluator()
                           .setLabelCol("ArrDelay")
                           .setPredictionCol("predictionLR")
                           .setMetricName("rmse")
    
    val lr_evaluator_r2 = new RegressionEvaluator()
                         .setLabelCol("ArrDelay")
                         .setPredictionCol("predictionLR")
                         .setMetricName("r2")
    
    val lr_cv_rmse = new CrossValidator()
                      .setEstimator(lr_pipeline)
                      .setEvaluator(lr_evaluator_rmse)
                      .setEstimatorParamMaps(lr_paramGrid)
                      .setNumFolds(3)
                      .setParallelism(3)
    
    val lr_cv_r2 = new CrossValidator()
                  .setEstimator(lr_pipeline)
                  .setEvaluator(lr_evaluator_rmse)
                  .setEstimatorParamMaps(lr_paramGrid)
                  .setNumFolds(3)
                  .setParallelism(3)
```

Something like this:

```
val lr_cv = new CrossValidator()
        .setEstimator(lr_pipeline)
        .setEvaluator(lr_evaluator_rmse)
        .setEvaluator(lr_evaluator_r2)
        .setEstimatorParamMaps(lr_paramGrid)
        .setNumFolds(3)
        .setParallelism(3)
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The PySpark documentation on [CrossValidator](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.ml.tuning.CrossValidator.html?highlight=crossvalidator) indicates that the `evaluator` argument is a single entity --> `evaluator: Optional[pyspark.ml.evaluation.Evaluator] = None`

The solution I went with was to create separate pipelines for each evaluator. For example,

```
from pyspark.ml.feature import VectorAssembler
from pyspark.ml import Pipeline
from pyspark.ml.classification import RandomForestClassifier
from pyspark.ml.evaluation import MulticlassClassificationEvaluator, BinaryClassificationEvaluator
from pyspark.ml.tuning import CrossValidator

# Convert inputs to vector assembler
vec_assembler = VectorAssembler(inputCols=[inputs], outputCol="features")

# Create Random Forest Classifier pipeline
rf = RandomForestClassifier(labelCol="label", seed=42)
multiclass_evaluator = MulticlassClassificationEvaluator(predictionCol="prediction", labelCol="label", metricName="accuracy")
binary_evaluator = BinaryClassificationEvaluator(rawPredictionCol="prediction", labelCol="label")

# Plop model objects into cross validator
cv1 = CrossValidator(estimator=rf, evaluator=multiclass_evaluator, numFolds=3, parallelism=4, seed=42)

cv2 = CrossValidator(estimator=rf, evaluator=binary_evaluator, numFolds=3, parallelism=4, seed=42)

# Put all step in a pipeline
pipeline1 = Pipeline(stages=[vec_assembler, cv1])
pipeline2 = Pipeline(stages=[vec_assembler, cv2])
```